# Where can i find the link to my newly created app in firebase?

Tags: firebase

Im trying to locate the link that is supposed to be created along with my app on Firebase(according to the udacity Firebase course).
I found many links but none of them were accepted by the "after lesson quiz" on udacity.
The content that they have is according to the old UI of Firebase so i cant follow it step by step.

Comment: This is one of those cases where seeing a screenshot of what you're trying to find will make it a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that course is for Firebase 2.x (www.firebase.com) and is out of date. In the [legacy Firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html), under step 5 : Read & Write to your Firebase Database, you can see that creating a Firebase reference required the actual web address for you app. This is no longer true.

**The new and correct way to setup your Firebase app does not require you to use this web address.** The steps for setting up a Firebase app now are [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This helped.